# Multiple Hypothesis testing correction on non-independent data

Tags: multiple-comparisons, change-point, bonferroni, structural-change

Consider a vector $X_i$ with $i \in [1,N]$. Let us say that you divide the vector into two $X_{i}'$ with $i \in [1,j]$ and $X_i''$ with $i \in [j+1, N]$ for several $j$; then for each  pair of sub-vectors associated with this $j$ you apply a test that delivers a p-value (like a Student's t-test or a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test).

As you change your separating index $j$ systematically and repeat the test, you are comparing datasets that overlap strongly. Is there a way to easily calculate the number of *independent tests* as required by the [Sidak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0id%C3%A1k_correction) or the [Bonferroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) corrections, so that one can apply one of these? One can assume the $j$ index covers a consecutive series of indexes $j \in [lim_1, lim_2]$. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that I am not searching for the number of different independent combinations in the groups but rather for the number of independent tests, which in my understanding is a different thing (but maybe might be expressed in number of different independent group combinations).

Comment: If there were a general answer to this question, there would be practically no literature on change-point analysis ([tag:change-point]) or structural change modeling ([tag:structural-change]). By exploring those subjects you can get a sense of the approaches people have taken to specific instances of your problem. (A simple degree-of-freedom correction is not going to be adequate in most circumstances.)

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the references, I will take a look at them.